# Scan other File in BaseTreeVisitor | Get Tree from other Java File

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i have a Problem with Sonarqube. I cant access the ClassTree from other class in the scanned Project.

Sample:

```
@Override
public void visitNewClass(NewClassTree tree) {

    Tree targetTree = semanticModel.getTree(tree.constructorSymbol());
    // Or Tree targetTree =
    // semanticModel.getTree(tree.constructorSymbol().Owner());

    super.visitNewClass(tree);

}
```

The targetTree is null. What is wrong? is it even possible?

Thank you!

best regards,
Michel

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to specify language and, presumably, the fact that you're trying to write... custom checks?

Comment: Hi, 

there are now new infos:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/QoVqxM7POmI